# Is the ideal $(X_0X_1+X_2X_3+\ldots+X_{n-1}X_n)$ prime?

Tags: commutative-algebra, polynomials

Consider the ideal $(f = X_0X_1+X_2X_3+\ldots+X_{n-1}X_n)$ in the polynomial ring $k[X_0,\ldots, X_n]$. Is this a prime ideal? If so, what is its height? I'm stuck trying to show that $f$ is irreducible.

Comment: To show that it is irreducible show that it is an irreducible element of $k[X_1,\dots,X_n][X_0]$, which is obvious because it has degree $1$.

Comment: X_0X_1 + X_1X_2 also has degree 1 over that ring.

Comment: Well, I did not mean that the reason for irreducibility is that it has degree one, but that it is obvious how to show it is irreducible because it has degree one :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $f$ factored non-trivially.  Since $f$ is homogeneous quadratic, we could write $f = L L'$ with $L$, $L'$ homogeneous linear polynomials.  What Mariano's argument shows is that any variable $X_i$ cannot occur in both $L$ and $L'$.  (Alternatively, if a variable $X_i$ did appear in both $L$ and $L'$, then $f$ would contain a term with $X_i^2$ in it.)  Suppose $L$ contains a term of the form $c X_0$ with $c \neq 0$.  Then $L'$ must contain the term $\frac{1}{c} X_1$ and cannot contain a term with any other variables, i.e. $L' = \frac{1}{c} X_1$.  But the same analysis shows that $L = c X_0$.  Conclusion: $f$ factors if and only if $n = 1$.

Comment: Great, thank you. Do you or someone else have an advice on how to compute the height of this prime, by any chance?